# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir 2 arreglos y que estos coincidan al ser impresos? (Ojo,uno de ellos en el procesos se reordena)

Tags: java, array, ordenamiento, imprimir

Este programa sirve para **registrar nombres de alumnos**, y sus respectivos promedios. El programa **realiza un reordenamiento de los promedios** , es decir, estos **se organizan de mayor a menor** promedio.

***El problema*** surge al imprimir los arreglos en consola, dado que obviamente imprime los nombres, tal cual fueron ingresados dentro del arreglo y obviamente **no coinciden con el arreglo ya ordenado de promedios**.
**Posible solución**
(En mi mente, por que no se que métodos y estructuras podrían usarse XD)
Se me ocurrió que lo único que los puede hacer coincidir, es el arreglo de promedios antes de ordenarse. Es decir, colocar un if y decir que si el **arreglo(i) sin ordenar** de promedios, es igual al **arreglo(i) ya ordenado**, entonces, que imprima el nombre del alumno en esa posicion.

si son diferentes, que compare en otra posición hasta que sean iguales e imprima el nombre en aquella posición.   He aquí mi código:

```
package Ordenamiento;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Escuela {

```
public void intinsertarAlumnos(String alumnos[], int promedios[]) {
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < alumnos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Digite el nomre del alumno" + (i + 1) + ":");
        alumnos[i] = teclado.next();
        System.out.print("Digite el promedio del alumno" + (i + 1) + ":");
        System.out.print(" ");
        promedios[i] = teclado.nextInt();
        int auxiliar = promedios[i];
    }

}

public void ordenarPromedios(int promedios[]) {
    int posicion, promedio;
    for (int i = 0; i < promedios.length; i++) {
        posicion = i;
        promedio = promedios[i];
        while ((posicion > 0) && (promedios[posicion - 1] > promedio)) {
            promedios[posicion] = promedios[posicion - 1];
            posicion--;
        }
        promedios[posicion] = promedio;
    }

}

public void OrdenarNombres(String alumnos[]) {
    String auxiliar;
    for (int i= 0; i < (alumnos.length - 1);i++){
for (int j = 0; j < (alumnos.length - 1); j++) {
            if (alumnos[j].compareTo(alumnos[j + 1]) > 0) {
                auxiliar = alumnos[j];
                alumnos[j] = alumnos[j + 1];
                alumnos[j + 1] = auxiliar;
            }
            
        }
    }
}

public void imprimirPromedios(String alumnos[], int promedios[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < promedios.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("[" + alumnos[i] + promedios[i]);
    }

}
package Ordenamiento;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Escuela escuela = new Escuela();
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
   
    int arreglo[], nElementos;
    System.out.print("Digite el numero de elementos: ");
    nElementos = teclado.nextInt();
    String alumnos[] = new String[nElementos];
    int promedio[] = new int[nElementos];
    
    escuela.intinsertarAlumnos(alumnos, promedio);
    escuela.ordenarPromedios(promedio);
    escuela.OrdenarNombres(alumnos);
    System.out.print("\nPromedios Ordenados: ");
    escuela.imprimirPromedios(alumnos, promedio);
```

Y bueno este es mi codigo, yo seguire trabajando en mi posible solucion, pero es un problema que surgio en clase, y me gustaria resolverlo, aunque nos dijeron que no era obligatorio. No espero que lo solucionen,pero si gustan, pues no estaria de mas he. Mas bien me encantaria que me digan que estructuras y metodos o tecnicas puedo utilizar. Espero con fe la respuesta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algunos detalles:

- Dices *se organizan de mayor a menor promedio*.Tal como tienes tu metodo `ordenarPromedios()` esto organiza los promedios de menor a mayor
- Dices que los nombres se organizan como se van ingresando,en realidad los estas organizando alfabéticamente al usar compare to

Solucion

Podes aprovechar el ordenamiento que tenes en el método `ordenarPromedios()` para ordenar el nombre de los alumnos ,ya que los indices ordenados en el array promedios también pueden aplicarse al array alumnos

Original

[0] Juan  13---  [1] Miguel 16--  [2] Mario 14--- [3] Diego 17

Ordenado de mayor a menor

[3] Diego 17---  [1] Miguel 16-- [2] Mario 14--- [0] Juan  13

```
public void ordenarPromediosyNombres(int promedios[],String[]alumnos) {
    int posicion, promedio;
    String nombre;
    for (int i = 0; i < promedios.length; i++) {
        posicion = i;
        promedio = promedios[i];
        nombre = alumnos[i];
        while ((posicion > 0) && (promedios[posicion - 1] < promedio)) {
            promedios[posicion] = promedios[posicion - 1];
            alumnos[posicion]=alumnos[posicion-1];
            posicion--;
        }
        promedios[posicion] = promedio;
        alumnos[posicion]=nombre;
    }

}
```

una recomendación seria hacer uso de un `hashMap`

Comment: Hola muchísimas gracias por responder mi comentario. Efectivamente me he equivocado, ese compare to lo puse ahi por que estaba probando ese método, pero nada que ver! Que vergüenza, eso debió ser muy confuso.     En mi defensa, soy un poco nuevo en este lugar.

Comment: si te sirvió la respuesta te invito a marcarla como aceptada ✓ ,saludos

Comment: Por supuesto, te agradezco el tiempo invertido. En cuanto acabe me gastaría que vieras mi solución. Saludos Saludos!!!